# euclidean distance between vectors grouped by other variable in SPSS, R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, vba, spss, euclidean-distance

I have a dataset containing something like this:

```
case,group,val1,val2,val3,val4
1,1,3,5,6,8
2,1,2,7,5,4
3,2,1,3,6,8
4,2,5,4,3,7
5,1,8,6,5,3
```

I'm trying to compute programmatically the Euclidean distance between the vectors of values in groups.

This means that I have x number of cases in n number of groups. The euclidean distance is computed between pairs of rows and then averaged for the group. So, in the example above, first I compute the mean and std dev of group 1 (case 1, 2 and 5), then standardise values (i.e. [(original value - mean)/st dev], then compute the ED between case 1 and case 2, case 2 and 5, and case 1 and 5, and finally average the ED for the group.

Can anyone suggest a neat way of achieving this in a reasonably efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of how I would approach this in SPSS, first lets read the example data into SPSS.

```
data list list (",") / case group val1 val2 val3 val4 (6F1.0).
begin data
1,1,3,5,6,8
2,1,2,7,5,4
3,2,1,3,6,8
4,2,5,4,3,7
5,1,8,6,5,3
end data.
dataset name orig.
```

Then we can use `SPLIT FILE` and `PROXIMITIES` to get our distance matrix by group. Note, as you mentioned in the comments to flodel's answer, this produces a seperate dataset we need to work with (also note case practically never matters in SPSS syntax, e.g. `split file` and `SPLIT FILE` are equivalent).

```
sort cases by group.
split file by group.
dataset declare dist.
PROXIMITIES val1, val2, val3, val4
/STANDARDIZE = Z
/MEASURE = EUCLID
/PRINT = NONE
/MATRIX = OUT('dist').
```

Unlike R, basically everything within an SPSS data matrix is like an R `data.frame`, so SPLIT file near functionally replaces all the different `*ply` functions in R. Very convienant, but less flexible in general. So now we need to aggregate the distances in the `dist` file I saved the results to. We first sum across rows, and then sum by group via an `AGGREGATE` command.

```
dataset activate dist.
compute dist_sum = SUM(VAR1 to VAR3).
*it appears SPSS keeps empty cases - we dont want them in the aggregation.
select if MISSING(dist_sum) = 0.
dataset activate dist.
DATASET DECLARE dist_agg.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE='dist_agg'
  /BREAK=group
  /dist_sum = SUM(dist_sum)
  /N_Cases=N.
dataset activate dist_agg.
compute mean_dist = dist_sum /(N_Cases*(N_Cases - 1)).
```

Here I save the aggregated results into another dataset named `dist_agg`. Because SPSS (annoyingly) saves the full distance matrix, the mean will not be `n*(n-1)/2` (as in the equivalent R syntax), but will be `n*(n-1)` assuming you do not want to count the diagonal elements towards the mean. Then we can just merge these back into the `orig` data file via a match files command.

```
*merge back into the original dataset.
dataset activate orig.
match files file = *
/table = 'dist_agg'
/by group.
exe.

*clean out old datasets if you like.
dataset close dist.
dataset close dist_agg.
```

The flexibility of R to go back and forth between `matrix` and `data.frame` objects makes SPSS a bit more clunky for this job. I could write a much more concise program to do this in SPSS's `MATRIX` language, but to do it across groups in `MATRIX` is a pain in the butt (compared to R's `*ply` syntax).

Comment: andy-w thanks for providing this solution with SPSS. I have to say that I understand it much more than the R solution coming from @flodel, but maybe it is because SPSS (in its clunkiness) makes each intermediate step visible! much appreciate your input

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is probably easier in R...

Your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(case  = 1:5, 
                  group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                  val1  = c(3, 2, 1, 5, 8),
                  val2  = c(5, 7, 3, 4, 6),
                  val3  = c(6, 5, 6, 3, 5),
                  val4  = c(8, 4, 8, 7, 3))
```

A short solution:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat[c("group", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")],
      "group", function(x)c(mean.ED = mean(dist(scale(as.matrix(x))))))
#   group  mean.ED
# 1     1 3.121136
# 2     2 3.162278
```

Comment: thanks this is brilliant, although i'll have to study the nesting in detail as i don't understand it... happy that it does the job though!

Comment: one more question, how do i make sure that if there are NA values the function is not returning NAs too, but skips the cases with missing data?

Comment: See the `na.rm` argument to the `mean` function.

Comment: +1 - SPSS it isn't hard (although not as concise as this). A simple workflow would be `SPLIT FILES` then, `PROXIMITIES` and then `AGGREGATE`.

Comment: @Andy W, the SPSS suggestion is quite interesting, would you mind suggesting the syntax for it? I've checked the docs for the PROXIMITIES function and found it **very very** handy as it allows to standardize vars on the go and creates the full matrix of distances, but i can't figure out how to use the output of this command as input of the AGGREGATE function (at the moment I'm at the stage where the result of PROXIMITIES is an intermediate step for manual computation later!) perhaps not as concise as the R version, but still quite compact!

Comment: For info this is the syntax where i got to:  `SORT CASES  BY group.
SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY group.

PROXIMITIES   val1, val2, val3, val4
   /STANDARDIZE = Z
   /MEASURE = EUCLID  
   /MISSING   = EXCLUDE      
. 
` There is a MATRIX output option, but i can't make it work as it is either saving out to a separate file or create a new dataset. I'm probably being a dummy somewhere, but just can't see it at the moment...

Comment: I will a seperate answer to illustrate in SPSS when I get a chance @lorenzov. FYI flodel, this appears to include the value for "group" in the distance calculation, I might suggest `ddply(dat[c("group", "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4")],
      "group", function(x)c(mean.ED = mean(dist(scale(as.matrix(subset(x, select = -group)))))))` but you would know better than me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution using base R.

```
d <- by (dat[,2:5], dat$group, function(x) dist(x))
```

sapply(d,mean)